# Как написать условие if многомерного массива?

Tags: javascript

имеется массив

```
[
    [
        {
            "id_user": "21",
            "value_sum": "45634"
        },
        {
            "id_user": "22",
            "value_sum": "4534"
        }
    ]
]
```

Необходимо найти в массиве, например, `id_user = 22`, если такой имеется, то ничего не делать, а если не имеется, то выполнить

```
add_user_awards.push({'id_user':id_row, 'value_sum':value_sum});
```

пробовал так:

```
let id_row = 22;
let value_sum = 4444;
if(add_user_awards[0]['id_user'].indexOf(id_row) > -1) {
    let test = true;
    console.log(test);
} else {
    add_user_awards.push({'id_user':id_row, 'value_sum':value_sum});
}
```

Ничего не вышло

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать функцию `find` для поиска объекта в массиве по значению его поля:

```
let id_row = 22;
let value_sum = 4444;
if(add_user_awards[0].find(function (user) { return user.id_user == id_row }) != null) {
    let test = true;
    console.log(test);
} else {
    add_user_awards[0].push({'id_user':id_row, 'value_sum':value_sum});
}
```